# Something wrong with this array sort (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have this :

```
class sorter {
    static void main(){
        int[] a={3,2,1}; int t=0;
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
            int small=a[i];
            for(int j=i+1; j<3; j++){
                if(a[j]<small){
                    small=a[j];
                    t=j;
                }
            }
            int tmp =a[i];
            a[i]=small;
            a[t]=tmp;
        }
        System.out.println(a[0]);
        System.out.println(a[1]);
        System.out.println(a[2]);
    }
}
```

Trying to sort this array however the output is :

```
1
2
2
```

I'd be really thankful if someone could just point out the mistake(s).

Comment: This is the kind of bug that is very easy to find out using a debugger, by stepping through the code line by line and watching the values of the variables. You should learn to use your debugger. It's super-simple, and it will save you hours and hours.

Comment: thanks, will try to use debuggers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your inner loop doesn't find anything smaller than `small`, it leaves `t` at the last value set. Since you are unconditionally swapping `a[i]` with `a[t]` after the inner loop exits, that can lead to erroneous swaps. You probably want to initialize `t` to `i` each time through the outer loop before entering the inner loop.

```
int[] a={3,2,1};
for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
    int small=a[i];
    int t = i;
    for(int j=i+1; j<3; j++){
        if(a[j]<small){
            small=a[j];
            t=j;
        }
    }
    if (i != t) {
        int tmp =a[i];
        a[i]=small;
        a[t]=tmp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your T is not reset

```
public class Sorter {
public static void main(String []args){
    int[] a={1,2,3,4,5,0,9,8,7,6};
    int t=0; // points to index of current smallest
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        t=i; // Point to current index of not sorted
        int smallest=a[i];
        for(int j=i+1; j<a.length; j++){
            if(a[j]<smallest){
                smallest=a[j];
                t=j;
            }
        }

        int tmp =a[i];
        a[i]=smallest;
        a[t]=tmp;
    }
    for (int i =0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}
```